# Error when including the pandas package in an executable application made with cx_freeze

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to build an application that can be run by some users. Therefore, to transform I used the cx_freeze library. However, when including the pandas package there is an error. When deleting it is generated without problems. Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os


class CLASSE():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def Test (self):
        nome = int(input('Yor Name! '))
        #df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(self.caminho, 'VP.xlsx'))
        print(nome)
        
    def ReadPandas(self):
        "read file using pandas"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dados = CLASSE()
    dados.Test()
```

code cx_freeze:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
        base = None   


executables = [Executable("testesa.py", base=base)]
include = ['os','pandas']
packages = []
exclude = []

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'includes':include,
        'packages':packages,
        'excludes': exclude,
    },
}

setup(
    name = "Nome Executavel",
    options = options,
    version = "1.0",
    author = 'Bittencourt, Wanderson',
    description = 'Descricao do seu arquivo',
    executables = executables
)
```

Error:

```
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 874, in __init__
    self.normalized = self.normalize(name)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 882, in normalize
    return re.sub(r"[-_.]+", "-", name).lower().replace('-', '_')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\re\__init__.py", line 185, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

As a result, I expected that the executable would be generated, but unfortunately it was not generated.

Comment: correction: in function
def ReadPandas(self):
        "read file using pandas"
        pass